# Use google colab full ram memory

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, google-colaboratory

I am training an artificial intelligence model, google colab provides me with 13 GB approximately, but when I run the training I only see that they run in 2 GB, the script has been running for 5 hours and it does not give the first result.

Does anyone know how I can use all the ram memory capacity?

This is the code I am running

```
scores_TEC = []

for model_name, mp in model_params.items():
  clf = GridSearchCV(mp['model'], mp['params'], cv=10, return_train_score=False)
  clf.fit(x_t,y_t)
  scores.append({
      'model': model_name,
      'best_score': clf.best_score_,
      'best_params': clf.best_params_
  })

# Models params

model_params = {
    'neighbors': {
        'model': KNeighborsClassifier(),
        'params': {
            'n_neighbors': np.arange(1,20),
            'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'],
            'p': [1,2,3,5]
        }
    },
    'svm': {
        'model': svm.SVC(),
        'params': {
            'C': np.arange(1,20),
            'kernel': ['lineal', 'poli', 'rbf', 'sigmoide'],
            'degree' : [1,2,3,4,5],
            'gamma': ['scale', 'auto'],
            'coef0': [1,2,3,4,5]
            
        }
    },
    
    'tree' : {
        'model': DecisionTreeClassifier(),
        'params': {
             'max_depth': [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21],
              'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
              'min_samples_split': [50,100,150],
              'min_samples_leaf': np.arange(50,100)
            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Using all RAM is not needed nor desirable, not sure why you are asking about this, the code uses as much RAM as needed and not more.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your training takes so long is because of the processing unit(s) used, not RAM.

At first, make sure that you are [using GPU](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/google_colab/google_colab_using_free_gpu.htm) instead of CPU.

If this still does not solve your problem, then you can consider purchasing [Colab Pro or Colab Pro+.](https://colab.research.google.com/signup) These plans give you access to better processing units, which should speed up your training.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will use it :)